# Correct usage of verb with neither and none?

Tags: pronouns, subject-verb-agreement

I got confused when my teacher's statements got contradicted. Unfortunately I was not able to clarify my doubt. The sentences were:

- None of the employees working in the office **have** invested in
  mutual  funds.
- Neither of the boys **has** submitted their records.

Why this variation in both the sentences? Could anyone explain the correct usage? My understanding says both should contain *have*. But I'm not sure.

**PS:** When I used **has** with the former he told its wrong and when I used **have** with latter one then again he said wrong.

Comment: Hi Sudhir, a question has been previously asked about neither/none (and "no one" as well) and whether or not they take singular or plural verbs. I'm closing this as a duplicate; if you have any questions or concerns about this please feel free to @ message me. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

With *none of* and *neither of*, you can use the singular or the plural verb.

> None of these pens works/work.

> We have three sons but none of them lives/live nearby.

> Neither of them has/have a car.

Clearly, it is not "Neither answer are correct."

#### Related questions

- ["None" as plural indefinite pronoun](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1425/none-as-plural-indefinite-pronoun)
- [Which is correct, "neither is" or "neither are"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/10304/which-is-correct-neither-is-or-neither-are)

Comment: You're sure that we can use either one i.e the singular or the plural verb?

Comment: The examples I used in my answer are taken from the OALD (_Oxford Advanced Learner's Dictionary_).

Comment: Interesting topic.. let us know more, kiam.